# JOGL, отрисовка текстуры

Tags: java, opengl, jogl

Начал работать с JOGL.

Не получается отрисовать текстуру. И дело даже не в 59 исключениях которыми меня заваливает Java&OpenGL, а в отсутствие более-менее понятного и актуального руководства на данную тему.

Прошу вас, привести простой пример кода отрисовки текстуры. При этом очень желательно использовать `glDrawArrays` / `glDrawElements`.

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос тот код, который должен рисовать, но не работает. Код при этом должен быть [минимальным и самодостаточным](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

как-то так:

```
  public void onDrawFrame(GL10 arg0) {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture2);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 4, 4);
}
```

..Здесь мы просим систему нарисовать треугольники сначала из первой четверки вершин, затем из второй четверки вершин. Каждая четверка даст нам по квадрату. А перед рисованием каждого квадрата, мы помещаем соответствующую ему текстуру в target, чтобы шейдер для первого квадрата использовал первую текстуру, а для второго квадрата – вторую...

Подробные уроки отрисовки текстуры с использованием [glDrawArrays](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/406-urok-175-opengl-tekstury.html) и [glDrawElements](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/408-urok-176-opengl-indeksy-tekstury-dlja-kuba.html)
__
**UPD1:** хорошим подспорьем будет [Графическая библиотека OpenGL(методическое пособие)](http://rsdn.org/article/opengl/ogltut2.xml#EBF)

Comment: Данный код не является самодостаточным, а также не объясняет каким образом отрисовать текстуру на определённых координатах.

Comment: @wcobalt сложно предоставить самодостаточный код когда автор вопроса предоставил ноль байт своего кода. **телепаты в отпуске** а так бы я догадался что там у него и продолжил с проблемного места. +ссылки на уроки как доехать до этого места я дал.